# Cannot change ggplot boxplot legend name

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot, tidy

I am using this code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape)
 mtcars <- melt(mtcars, id="am")
 mtcars$am <- as.character(mtcars$am)
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(color = am), width = 0.4, size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(0.6), 
        outlier.shape=NA, notch=T) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name="No name", labels=c("A", "B")) + #Why does this line not work?
    coord_flip()
 p
```

Why do the legend name and variable names not change? How can I change them?

Comment: Try putting `name="No name", labels=c("A", "B")` in with `scale_color_manual()` instead of in `scale_fill_discrete()` maybe?

Comment: Wow, yes, that works! Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
mtcars <- melt(mtcars, id="am")
mtcars$am <- as.character(mtcars$am)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = am), width = 0.4, size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(0.6), 
               outlier.shape=NA, notch=T) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"),
                     name="No name", labels=c("A", "B")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) + 
  coord_flip()
p
```

[image: example_1.png]

The issue is that you don't use "fill" in the plot (you use "color"), so adjusting the "fill" scale doesn't have any effect.

Also, change `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` to `guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` to reverse the legend order.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Thank you so much. :)